# Insert Data to database not working

Tags: php, html

i have this html form

```
<div class="box box-info">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
          <h3 class="box-title">Please Input Below Information</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <!-- form start -->
        <form method="POST" action="model.php" class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Model Code *</label>

              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="ModelCode" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="e.g KTI">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Model Name *</label>

              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ModelName" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="e.g 0002">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Model Units *</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control" name="ModelUnit" style="width: 100%;">
              <option value="" selected disabled>Choose Model Unit</option>
               <?php
               $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select departmentname from department");
               while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['departmentname']; ?>"><?php echo $row['departmentname']; ?></option>
                <?php
                }
               ?>
            </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Model Hour Theroy *</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control" name="ModelHourT" style="width: 100%;">
              <option value="" selected disabled>Choose Model Hour</option>
               <?php
               $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select GroupTeory from grouptheory");
               while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['GroupTeory']; ?>"><?php echo $row['GroupTeory']; ?></option>
                <?php
                }
               ?>
            </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Model Hour Practice *</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control" name="ModelHourP" style="width: 100%;">
              <option value="" selected disabled>Choose Model Practice</option>
               <?php
               $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select GroupPractical from grouppractical");
               while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['GroupPractical']; ?>"><?php echo $row['GroupPractical']; ?></option>
                <?php
                }
               ?>
            </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Model Type *</label>

              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="ModelType" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="e.g KTI">
              </div>
            </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Semister *</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" name="SemsterID">
              <option value="" selected disabled>Choose Model Type</option>
               <?php
               $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select Semester from semester");
               while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['Semester']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Semester']; ?></option>
                <?php
                }
               ?>
            </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->
          <div class="box-footer">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" value="Submit" />
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-footer -->
        </form>

      </div>
```

and this is my php insert function

```
include("Connection.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo "<script>alert($query1)</script>";
$ModelCode = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['ModelCode']);
$ModelName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['ModelName']);
$ModelUnit = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['ModelUnit']);
$ModelHourT =mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['ModelHourT']);
$ModelHourP = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['ModelHourP']);
$ModelType = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['ModelType']);
$SemsterID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['SemsterID']);

$query1 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO 'model'                   (ModelCode,ModelName,ModelUnit,ModelHourTheory,ModelHourPractical,ModelType,StageID) VALUES    ('$ModelCode','$ModelName','$ModelUnit','$ModelHourT','$ModelHourP','$ModelType'    ,'$SemsterID')");
echo "<script>alert($query1)</script>";
}
```

and it doesn't work .... i didn't no what's happen !! even i have been compare fields of the table with the name of the database ... but it still doesn't work ... anyone knows what is problem ?

Comment: Whats the error in console?

Comment: it didn't give me any error ... the page have been reloaded but the data not store in database ... if you see my last line i have print the query , but the query return empty .

Answer (score 0):

You don't should use single quote for table name  (in this case single quote is for literal value  )

Assuming that you table is named model you should use

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($con, 
    "INSERT INTO model (ModelCode, ModelName,ModelUnit,
                        ModelHourTheory,ModelHourPractical,ModelType,StageID) 
             VALUES    ('$ModelCode','$ModelName','$ModelUnit',
                        '$ModelHourT','$ModelHourP','$ModelType','$SemsterID')");
```

Comment: i have tested this once ... but it still not working

Comment: are you sure that the $_POST is correct ?  try var_dump($_POST) and check  if you have submit entry

Comment: print this thing 

http://www.webchinupload.com/f/2017-03/18fe55854b29596a5160ddb5827a6ab0.JPG

Comment: i have populate all the values .. i think it means all variable have values

Comment: and the alert($query1)   what's  return?

Comment: nothing ... empty value. i have tested one by one the problem is dropdown .. if i remove dropdown from insert query it doesn't have any problem data would be inserted successfully with textboxes ... but when i add dropdown the problem still happened ... but what's wrong with dropdown ?

Comment: The alert should retunr or 1 or 0  (alias or true or false)  ... and dropbox or  textbox the value you insert are the value  submittedn (alias present in $_POST)  .. if you have a valid submit with valid data for all the coumn the values must be inserted .. orthewise you should have an errror .. of message that you are not connected  to db

Comment: bro ... the problem is not db believe me ... cause with texbox it doesn't have any problem ... it has problem with dropdown . also all column with value are valid .

Comment: Your question have title    "Insert Data to database not working" ... so you have all the value correctly in $_POST .. then these value  must be inserted  in db ... this not  depending how you have obtained the value in $_POST  .by dropbox or inputbox ..  ... otherwise you question have at  least a wrong  title  ...

Comment: just for test instead  remove the first 'echo "<script>alert($query1)</script>";' ( the top one )   .in you php insert function .. you are referring to a $query that is not valirized ..

Comment: bro i have fixed problem ... the problem was data type i input as text and datatype of the field is int ... thanks for your advance